# ESLint error after switching to VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

I just switched to VS Code and installed the ESLint extension, I'm getting the following error:

```
[Info  - 15:29:51] ESLint server is running.
[Info  - 15:29:53] ESLint library loaded from: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/eslint/lib/api.js
[Error - 15:29:53] Cannot read config file: /Users/carlosgrijalva/.eslintrc Error: unexpected end of the stream within a flow collection at line 24, column 1:
```

No idea what this is, can anyone lead me to the right direction?

This is what I have in my `.eslintrc`

```
{
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true,
        "jquery": true
},

    "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": [1,{"argsIgnorePartern": "res|next|~err"}],
    "arrow-body-style": ["error", "as-needed"],
    "no-param-reassign": [2, { "props": false }],
    "no-console": 0,
    "import": 0,
    "func-names": 0,
    "space-before-function-paren": 0,
    "comma-dangle": 0,
    "max-len": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "react/prefer-es6-class": 0,
    "radix": 0,
    "arrow-parens": [2, "as-needed"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the closing bracket in your .eslint file.  Try adding a closing bracket to the end of the file and see if that helps.